# in-page anchor with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

**Hi everyone,**

I am developing a backbone app and I went through one "big" problem, I can't find any useful thinking on internet but I can't imagine I am the only one to have this problem.

I just want to use basic in-page anchor with backbone like old time.

Example : I want to my page to go down to a section when I have #section at the end of the URL.
My backbone url path is site.com/#/page .... so of course site.com/#/page#section will freak out.

The only solution I found is to use push state but I don't really want to.

Is there another way to handle this behaviour ? even with another pattern or plugin .. but no push state.

Thanks very much,

**jdmry**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing it:

First, add `Backbone.history.anchor`

```
pathParts = Backbone.history.fragment.split('#')
Backbone.history.anchor = pathParts[1]
```

Then, use jQuery to scroll to the element

```
if (Backbone.history.anchor) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + Backbone.history.anchor).offset().top - 10
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but does it mean I need to add a route for each possible anchor ?..
Like : page#section page#otherSection ...
Because I also handle 404 with a *something route

Comment: I'm not sure. My entire app runs from the *catchall route so in my case it doesn't matter. I'm not sure how it would work in your case.